# How to write a function that deletes user from Firestore and file from Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

In my app, I allow my users revoke their access. So when a user is deleted from the Firebase Authentication, I have a function that deletes the user from Firestore:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  const uid = user.uid;

  return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .delete();
});
```

Which works fine. The problem is that I want to delete the profile picture that is stored in Firebase Storage at: `images/uid.png` as well. So how to delete the document in Firestore together with the image in Storage, **only if the image exists**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Admin SDK for Cloud Storage ([API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#delete)) as follows:

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {

    try {
        const uid = user.uid;

        await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(uid)
            .delete();

        const file = admin.storage().bucket().file(`images/${uid}.png`);
        const fileExists = await file.exists();
        if (fileExists) {
            await file.delete();    
        }
        
        return true;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return true;
    }
});
```

---

Note that you could also use the [Delete User Data extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data) which is exactly done for this case: "Deletes data keyed on a userId from Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, or Cloud Storage when a user deletes their account. "

Comment: What happens if the image doesn't exist?

Comment: An error will be thrown (but note that the Firestore doc will still be deleted if it exists). So it's up to you to check if the image exists. You can use the the `exists()` method as @Wandrille shown in his answer. See the adapted code. Also note that the two deletions cannot be encapsulated in an atomic operation since they concern different Firebase services.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you delete your picture with the user deletion?

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  const uid = user.uid;
  const picture = admin.storage().bucket().file(`images/${uid}.png`);

  return picture
    .exists()
    .then(() => imageRef.delete())
    .finally(() => admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).delete());
});
```

Note, if the image doesn't exist, it will throw an error. But the `finally` will handle it properly in order to run the deletion.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with Renaud answer as it uses await async. Voted up.